# Photo cover in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, html

Today I'm working on the https://www.vanleeuwenemmen.nl/winkel/ website. But the image there is incorrect, because I've set the img to object-fit: contain, but if I leave it blank, then it is a weird photo that is zoomed in.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using cropped image. Your image is 300x300 cropped while the section is bigger. Your first div is already set to 40% width, so limiting the **image** to 40% in that section doesn't make sense. Use properly sized thumbnail or actual image.

Here is the result i got using actual image **`/3dcc1cba-c209-4a1a-a1f2-edd17fc8b58e.jpg`** &  **NOT** `3dcc1cba-c209-4a1a-a1f2-edd17fc8b58e-300x300.jpg` using following CSS:

```
.woocommerce li.product .entry-featured img {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @Arsalan Mithani

Comment: No problem, please consider accepting this answer if it helped. Thank you